# Does backbone trigger .add when a collection is .fetched?

Tags: backbone.js

I am converting my backbone app so that it starts communicating with the server, previously I had just been populating the collection with test data using `.add()`

I have tied some events to the collections add event. So every time an item is added to the collection I can render the view and update some statistics.

it appears that as soon as i add the `.fetch()` call to get data from the server the add events stop.

for example

```
var PayableCommitmentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:PayableCommitment,
    url:"/cc/account/contributions/",

    initialize: function() {
        this.bind("add",this.setInitialAmount,this);
    }
 }
```

`this.SetInitialAmount()` is never called after fetch creates the models in the collection.

I also have 2 views that are watching for items to be added to this collection that are now not updating.

My obvious work around is to write my own AJAX call so that I can add the items the same way I have been during development so far, however I'm sure backbone has the smarts to help me out here.

Can anyone suggest a way i can bind to the completion of fetch, or to make it stimulate the add event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch):

> **fetch** `collection.fetch([options])`
>
> Fetch the default set of models for this collection from the server, resetting the collection when they arrive.

And a [`reset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset):

> **reset** `collection.reset(models, [options])`
>
> Adding and removing models one at a time is all well and good, but sometimes you have so many models to change that you'd rather just update the collection in bulk. Use **reset** to replace a collection with a new list of models (or attribute hashes), triggering a single `"reset"` event at the end.

So a `fetch` will trigger a single `"reset"` event rather than a bunch of `"add"` events. You need a collection-wide version of `setInitialAmount` that you can bind to `"reset"`.

---

In Backbone 1.0, [`Collection#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) has this to say:

> **fetch** `collection.fetch([options])`
>
> Fetch the default set of models for this collection from the server, setting them on the collection when they arrive.
>   [...]
>   The behavior of **fetch** can be customized by using the available `set` options. For example, to fetch a collection, getting an `"add"` event for every new model, and a `"change"` event for every changed existing model, without removing anything: `collection.fetch({remove: false})`

So, if you're using 1.0+ then all you need to do is call your `fetch` with the `remove: false` option.

Comment: thanks, this made reset make more sense. I had assumed that the collection came back empty. I was also able to change my test harness out to use reset as well.

Comment: In Backbone 1.0.0 you now accomplish this by passing `remove: false` as an option to `fetch`.

Comment: @Radu: Thanks for the heads up. Better now?

Comment: Can the behaviour `reset` be customized by using the available `set` options as well? For example, if I wanted to fire `add` events during `reset`.

Comment: @fortuneRice: `reset` calls `add` as `this.add(models, _.extend({silent: true}, options));` and the `silent:true` should turn off the events from `this.add` so you'd probably need to add `silent:false` to the options (which might have undesirable side effects).

Answer (score 6):

The **fetch** method accepts a hash of options. One of these options can be the "add" option, which calls **add** on the collection instead of **reset**.

```
collection.fetch({ add: true });
```

Comment: No longer works for Backbone 1.0.0. See comment on above answer.